# jQuery WayPoints: Get Current or Active Waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I would like to return the current or active waypoint that is in the viewport when I click anywhere on the document.

I already have the following function written and it works perfectly.

```
$('.point').waypoint(function(e, direction) {
    var $active = $(this),
        index,
        points = $('.point').length - 1,
        $caption = $('.caption').first(),
        caption;

    index = $active.index('.point');

    if (direction === "up") {
        $active = $active.prev();

        index = $active.index('.point');

        if($active.index('.point') === -1) {
            index = 0;
            $('.bottom-nav').slideUp();
        }
    } else {
        if($active.index('.point') === 1) {
            index = 0;
            $('.bottom-nav').slideDown();
        }           
    }

    caption = $active.data('caption');

    if(caption) {
        $caption.html('').append(caption);
    } else {
        $caption.html('');
    }

    currentSlide(index);
}, { offset: 72 });
```

What I would like to do, though is to be able to access the current waypoint from the global $.waypoints object. More specifically, to return the current waypoint when I click the document. Something like:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    var index = $.waypoints('current');
});
```

Although obviously that syntax doesn't exist.

What's the best way to return the current waypoint?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused - do you want to grab the waypoint object for the selector that is visible itself, or the selector that has an enabled waypoint on it?

Comment: For the selector that's visible! Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a waypoint/waypoints, can you cache the selector that is having the waypoint applied to it, and call that variable whenever you want to get a list of enabled waypoints?

You could then remove the selector from the variable once you've disabled the waypoint.

Comment: Did this work for you?  I'll happily take an accepted answer if so.  ;)

Comment: Generally speaking yes, that did work for me. Can you please include some code so your answer could help other people as well?